# JFormattedTextField disappear in Design View

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

[image]

So I am working on a JFrame and I created some JFormattedTextFields. At the beginning every time I switched between Desing View and "Source" the Components stayed in Design View. But suddenly every time I switch to the Design Mode the Textfield disappear but when I execute the program they are shown. What can be the cause of that?

Here is my Panel where I add the Textfields:

```
private JPanel getPanel_2() {
    if (panelFishData == null) {
        panelFishData = new JPanel();
        panelFishData.setBounds(161, 23, 253, 264);
        panelFishData.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 0, 0));
        panelFishData.add(getLblName());
        panelFishData.add(getFormatedTextFieldNameFish());
        panelFishData.add(getLblMinWeight());
        panelFishData.add(getFormattedTextFieldMinWeight());
        panelFishData.add(getLblMaxWeight());
        panelFishData.add(getFormattedTextFieldMaxWeight());
        panelFishData.add(getLblstOccurence());
        panelFishData.add(getFormattedTextFieldFirstOccurence());
    }
    return panelFishData;
}
```

Here is one of my JFormattedTextFields:

```
private JFormattedTextField getFormattedTextFieldMinWeight() {
    MaskFormatter mf = createMinWeightMask();

    if (formattedTextFieldMinWeight == null) {
        formattedTextFieldMinWeight = new JFormattedTextField(mf);
    }
    return formattedTextFieldMinWeight;
}

private MaskFormatter createMinWeightMask() {
    MaskFormatter mf;
    try{
        mf = new MaskFormatter("### g");  
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        mf=null; 
    }
    return mf;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code:

```
    MaskFormatter mf = createMinWeightMask();
```

IN the if statement. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netbeans :

Check the layout of the panel on which yo are adding JFormattedTextFields , and go to Navigator panel to select your Field to enable the same again .